# I want to upload excel files from Android app data to firebase cloud

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an App that reads data and inputs into Excel files stored in **/Internal storage/android/data/files**.
I want to send the App file containing the excel docs to Firebase cloud.

When executing the code below? I get the following errors.
could not retrieve file size is the main error. something to do with the app file path

```java
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

       //save data to local storage
       binding.ivQr.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
           //initiate alertDiolog
           new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                   .setTitle("Save")
                   .setMessage("Data has been saved in to local storage of the phone")
                   .setPositiveButton("OK",(dialog, whichButton) -> {
                       // TODO: send or do something with data

                   uploadDataToStorage();

               }).show();
       });
   }
   private void uploadDataToStorage(){
       StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
       Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("Internal storage/Android/data/com.example.app/files"));

       StorageReference excelFiles = storageRef.child("com.example.app/"+file.getLastPathSegment()); 
       excelFiles.putFile(file);

       // handle uploadTask

      }
}
```

error

```
could not retrieve file size for upload file:///Internal storage/Android/data/com.example.app/files
                                               java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:342)
                                                at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:229)
                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1844)
                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1682)
                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1629)
                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(UploadTask.java:139)
                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(StorageReference.java:241)
                                                at com.example.scanqrapp.ui.main.MainFragment.uploadDataToStorage(MainFragment.java:165)
                                                at com.example.scanqrapp.ui.main.MainFragment.lambda$onViewCreated$0$com-example-scanqrapp-ui-main-MainFragment(MainFragment.java:93)
                                                at com.example.scanqrapp.ui.main.MainFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
                                                at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:188)
                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
could not locate file for uploading:file:///Internal storage/Android/data/com.example.app/files
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct path to upload the data?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, this is the path from the apps internal storage where the data I want to send to storage is saved. The data is not phone's/external data. It is saved inside the apps Android folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("Internal storage/Android/data/com.example.app/files"));
```

...you're trying to build the location to your app's internal data directory manually using hard-coded paths. You can't do it like that - the actual path will be very different on different devices. (And incidentally I don't know any Android device where the internal storage directory path is like the one you have).

Instead use `Context.getFilesDir()`. That gives you the location of your app's scoped internal storage directory, and you can work from there.

Comment: That is the apps internal storage folder, I am trying to send files from that path to storage.  I tried to use `Context.getFilesDir()` but it doesnt work  with 
`Uri file = Uri ***************`

Comment: You can get a URI from a File object like this: `URI.fromFile(File(context.getFilesDir(), "my-file-name"))` - note how I've used `File(parent, child)` to point to a file inside of the app's internal storage folder

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I used `requireContext().getExternalFilesDir()`
But I only send the child file to storage.  e.g `Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir("building1.xls"))));`

e.g. I have a path like this **files/building** my goal is to send the parent file to storage with the content. i get errors when I try this methods.

Comment: `Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir("com.example.app")), "files"))`

or 
`Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir("files"))))`
I want to point the URI path to the files folder. Thanks

Comment: OK, so as I understand it you have a document inside the 'files' folder in your app's externalFilesDir. So <external files dir>/files/building1.xls. Right? In that case you want something like `Uri.fromFile(new File(new File(getExternalFilesDir(), "files"), "building1.xls"))`. You can next File objects to describe a tree like that.

Comment: I  have so many files in the **/files/** folder. I want to send the files folder to storage, not its child, but when I point the path to the **/files/** folder, I get an error. It only works when I point the path to a file in the folder. E.g **building1.xls** or **building2.xls** .
I have tried `.getParent()` `.getParentDir()` `.getParentFile()`. When I check the debug logs, it points to the **files** dir but doesn't upload to the cloud.
`could not locate file for uploading:file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.scanqrapp/files
  StorageException has occurred.` @HughHughTeotl

Comment: let's say this is the path:      _<external_dir>/**files**/so many children_  .
My goal is to upload many children at once. But I can only point the path to one child.
So, when I point the path to **/files/** which has all the children. I get an error.

Comment: Correct, yes. You can only upload single files at a time.